# Oxygen builder / PHP Struggling to create dynamic property

Tags: php, wordpress, oxygenbuilder

When debugging my site to figure out why I'm occasionally (and seemingly, quite randomly) not able to save any edits I'm making to my site I came across this.

Well, there are actually 37 similar errors to this:

> PHP Deprecated    Creation of dynamic property EDD_SL_Plugin_Updater_Oxygen

Using the latest PHP and the latest version of Oxygen.

The error occurred since updating oxygen so naturally I tried restoring and using an older version.

I´ve also done the usual, signing all short codes, clearing all caches etc.

I'm just about to go in with a new staging copy to try it out with all my existing templates and components on a 'new' site.

Answer (score 1):

It is PHP 8.2 https://php.watch/versions/8.2/dynamic-properties-deprecated

You may:

1. Downgrade to PHP 8.1
2. Exclude E_DEPRECATED from error level: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
3. Or just wait for the plugin update

Also you can add `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` before class in `EDD_SL_Plugin_Updater_Oxygen.php`, but it will disappear after an update

Answer (score 0):

Before update the Oxygen builder and your PHP to the last version, check the [requirements and recommendations](https://oxygenbuilder.com/documentation/getting-started/requirements/#oxygen) of oxygen:

1. PHP Versions: **7.4, 8.0, 8.1**
2. PHP Modules: SimpleXML
3. Server Memory: 256 MB (512 MB is preferred)
4. WP Memory Limit: 256 MB (512 MB is preferred)

With that, you can't use the last PHP version available.